When starting Quarkus with quarkus:dev in IntelliJ IDEA, the console displays Chinese text as garbled characters
I have tried encoding in the startup parameter Settings file, as well as specifying the encoding in the maven configuration
mvn version
F:\ $ mvn -version
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:  -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Apache Maven 3.9.6 (bc0240f3c744dd6b6ec2920b3cd08dcc295161ae)
Maven home: D:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.6
Java version: 17.0.9, vendor: GraalVM Community, runtime: D:\Program Files\Java\graalvm-community-jdk-17.0.9
Default locale: zh_CN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

java version
F:\ $ java -version
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:  -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
openjdk version "17.0.9" 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 17.0.9+9.1 (build 17.0.9+9-jvmci-23.0-b22)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 17.0.9+9.1 (build 17.0.9+9-jvmci-23.0-b22, mixed mode, sharing)


        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
        <quarkus.platform.version>3.8.3</quarkus.platform.version>
        <quarkus-cxf-bom.version>3.8.3</quarkus-cxf-bom.version>

these is my boot parameters
-Dmaven.test.skip=true compile quarkus:dev -pl device-manager-robot -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.language=UTF-8

            <plugin>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <file.encoding>UTF-8</file.encoding>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

And I've specified that both the file encoding and the console encoding are UTF8, and that file.encoding=UTF-8 is set in the idea64.properties file, and I've changed almost every place I can think of where I can specify the encoding, but in the console output, Chinese characters are still garbled.
enter image description here
enter image description here
    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    public YCRobotInfo findById(Long id) {
        log.info("find by id - {}", "中文");
        return repository.findById(id);
    }

2024-05-11 15:12:24,683 INFO  13816 --- [        executor-thread-1] com.o.r.resource.RobotInfoResource        : find by id - ����

I changed everything I could think of to specify the encoding, but the console output was still garbled
